# Amazon.com MWS via PHP

Tags: php, amazon-mws

Here is what I want to do:

1. Access my Amazon Marketplace
2. Generate and save a report as a CSV file.  It must include the following information: ORER-ID, PURCHASE DATE, SKU, PRODUCT NAME, SELL PRICE, and SHIPPING INFORMATION

MWS is a mess.  If I'm wrong, please let me know!!

I believe that I have to REQUEST the report first and somehow wait until the report is generated.

Once the Report is generated, I should be able to pull the Report ID and get the information from that.  Am I right?  Is there a sample available showing this process?  Any pitfalls I should watch out for?

I am an intermediate PHP Programmer with limited API/Object Oriented programming knowledge.  I have been able to successfully program a site to pull orders ONE-BY-ONE but this throttles the system and locks me out of for a time.  I need to send ONE REQUEST for the report instead of several requests for individual orders.

Comment: Good luck. I agree that MWS is a mess.

Comment: You could just use scratchpad to get the http content that is needed. Then, you can build it from there. MWS is not that much of a mess, but they do make it fairly hard for anyone to integrate with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PHP as I use C#, but hopefully these steps will help:

```
    /*  To generate a report follow the following steps:              
        * 
        *  1. Create a RequestReportRequest object and populate the required information (merchantID, start date, end date etc.) 
        *  2. Request the report by creating a RequestReportResponse object and executing the service RequestReport method using the object name you instantiated in step 1 and set
        *     string requestID = reportResponse.RequestReportResult.ReportRequestInfo.GeneratedReportId to hold the generated report ID. 
        *  3. Create a GetReportRequestListRequest object and populating the required information. 
        *  4. Request the status of the reports by creating a GetReportRequestListResponse object and executing the GetReportRequestList method using the object name you 
        *     instantiated in step 3. 
        *  5. Execute scheduled checks for the status every 60 seconds using a while loop and a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000) call. This is often within the main program. 
        *  6. Create a foreach loop by creating a ReportRequestInfo object and looping over the GetReportRequestListResult.ReportRequestInfo objects within the 
        *     GetReportRequestListResponse object you instantiated in step 4. 
        *  7. Depending upon the status of the report complete any additional processing required. This is often within the main program
        *  8. Once the report returns _DONE_ the report is ready for download. this is often within the main program
        *  9. Request the report by creating a GetReportRequest object and set the report ID to match the GeneratedReportId object of the ReportRequestInfo object that was 
        *     instantiated in step 6. 
        * 10. Set the Report object of the GetReportRequest object instantiated in step 9 to System.IO.File.Open("filename", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite) in 
        *     order to download the report to disk in a streaming fashion. **NOTE** An error of "Uninitilized object reference" will be returned if this is not done! 
        * 11. Request the report by creating a GetReportResponse object and executing the service.GetReport method with the GetReportRequest object instantiated in step 9. 
        * 12. The report has been downloaded and processing can be passed off to other methods. 
        *
        */
```

It took me a while of trial and error to get this working, The API's are OK once you understand what each class is and more specifically *where* it needs to be instantiated.

The report type I think you are looking for is: _GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_ as it contains the majority of info.

I hope these steps help though - it would have saved me a week of debugging had I known them ahead of time :)

Answer (score 0):

The Temboo SDK RetrieveReport function lets you perform all the steps involved in downloading a single report (request, poll for status, retrieve completed report data) in a single call. The SDK is available for a number of languages, including Java, PHP, Python, Ruby, Node.js, etc., and is an open download. Take a look at:

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Amazon/Marketplace/Reports/RetrieveReport/

(Full disclosure: I work for Temboo)